# Jquery: SlideToggle on List with divs

Tags: jquery, accordion, slidetoggle

I'm trying to use list elements to build a simple menu for my website. 
The thing is that i want to show the '.second-row' div when the arrow is clicked and hide any other that is open, but all the ways i tried wasnt working.

Somebody could help me? 
The example is [here](http://bit.ly/ZmZRHP)

Comment: I checked your jsfiddle, its working as you wanted. it is toggling perfectly.I m not sure if i have understood your question wrong .let me know whats your exact req.

Comment: the slide is working, but when i click the two lists show the two divs, and hide the two too. I need it to hide one and show another :)

Comment: you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/YmqVa/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the `second-row` which corresponds to the `arrow-1` that was clicked:

```
$('a.arrow-1 ').click(function () {
    $('.second-row').slideUp();
    $(this).parent('.first-row').siblings('.second-row').slideDown();
});
```

#### [Here's an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mLBWC/4/)

**Note:** You'll probably want to add some logic to check the last clicked `arrow-1`, and return if it's the same as the current clicked one so that the `slideUp()/slideDown()` doesn't occur when clicking the same `arrow-1` twice.

Comment: Thank you very much, not only to update the fiddle, but to explain to me how it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

I just changed on click event a bit

```
$('a.arrow-1 ').click(function () {
            //alert("clicked");
            var cli=$(this).closest('li').find('.second-row');
            alert(cli);
            $(cli).slideToggle();
        });
```

you can get the working copy from [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/mLBWC/8/)

Happy coding :)